# problems with sql statements

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 tables

```
chat_rooms 
chat_name | chat_url | chat_id


chat_msgs
msg_chat_id | timestamp
```

I'm trying to display it like this :

```
-------- chat rooms that were active last 10 minutes---------
chat_name | chat_url | count the messages
```

Please help

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: MySql PHPMYADMIN WEB SERVER

Comment: You can edit your question to add the relevant information. You can also help others to help you by posting the SQL query you are using, as well as the environment you are trying to display the information in (e.g. HTML, shell/ terminal etc)

Answer (score 2):

Left join the messages to the chats on the chat ID and filtered for the last 10 minutes using `timestampadd()`. Then group by the chat room taking the count of timestamps.

```
SELECT cr.chat_name,
       cr.chat_url,
       count(cm.timestamp) "count the messages"
       FROM chat_rooms cr
            LEFT JOIN chat_msgs cm
                      ON cm.msg_chat_id = cr.chat_id
                         AND cm.timestamp >= timestampadd(minute, -10, now())
                         AND cm.timestamp < now()
       GROUP BY cr.chat_name,
                cr.chat_url;
```